# Add class if field is already filled VueJS

Tags: forms, vue.js, input

I am new in Vue and I need to add a new class to div.input-box where inside is label and input.
I can try more options after google but nothing to help me.

html:

```
 <form id="form" class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center mt-5">
      <div class="input-box col-lg-6" @click="isActive = 1"  :class="{'focus': isActive === 1}">
        <label class="input-label">
          {{ $t("system.first_name") }}
        </label>
        <input type="text" class="input-1" v-model="first_name" @focus="isActive = true" @blur="isActive = false">
      </div>
      <div class="input-box col-lg-6" @click="isActive = 2" :class="{'focus': isActive === 2}">
        <label class="input-label">
          {{ $t("system.last_name") }}
        </label>
        <input type="text" class="input-1" v-model="last_name" @focus="isActive = true" @blur="isActive = false">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="input-box col-lg-12" @click="isActive = 3" :class="{'focus': isActive === 3}">
        <label class="input-label">
          E-mail
        </label>
        <input type="text" class="input-1" v-model="email" @focus="isActive = true" @blur="isActive = false">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

script:

```
export default {
  name: "RegistrationSecondVersion",
  data(){
    return {
      isActive: false,
      first_name: null,
      last_name: null,
      email: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    checkForInput: function (e) {
      let input = e.target;
      if (input.value != '') {
        input.classList.add('focus');
      } else {
        input.classList.remove('focus');
      }
    }

  }
}
```

I had added the function in input but I need after filled to get 'focus' class to div.input-box.

Thank you so much!

Comment: I just have update my answer since a thought it wasn't really relevant to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `checkForInput` function whenever an input occurs. On the other hand, I see no need to use `@blur` and `@focus` in your case.

Try this:

```
 <form id="form" class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center mt-5">
      <div class="input-box col-lg-6" @click="isActive = 1"  :class="{'focus': isActive === 1}">
        <label class="input-label">
          {{ $t("system.first_name") }}
        </label>
        <input type="text" class="input-1" v-model="first_name" @input="checkForInput">
      </div>
      <div class="input-box col-lg-6" @click="isActive = 2" :class="{'focus': isActive === 2}">
        <label class="input-label">
          {{ $t("system.last_name") }}
        </label>
        <input type="text" class="input-1" v-model="last_name" @input="checkForInput">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="input-box col-lg-12" @click="isActive = 3" :class="{'focus': isActive === 3}">
        <label class="input-label">
          E-mail
        </label>
        <input type="text" class="input-1" v-model="email" @input="checkForInput">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```